# Change font in bibliography title, \refname does not work

Tags: fonts, bibliographies

I am trying to change title of section references. I know that this question was asked before, unfortunately their solution didn't helped me. I am using **MiKTeX 2.9** version 0.4.3. r.857, **BibTeX** database created by **Mendeley Desktop** version 1.5.2.

here is the relevant part of the code in the begining:

```
.
[irrelevant code]
.
\newcommand{\artitle}[1]{\Huge #1}
\newcommand{\arauthor}[2]{\Large \emph{#2}$^{#1}$}
\newcommand{\sppart}[1]{\begin{center}{ \parskip = 2\baselineskip \smal \MakeUppercase{#1}}\\[0.3cm]\end{center}}
.
[irrelevant code]
.
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain]{caption}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
.
[document] 
.
```

Here is the code of references:

```
\sppart{acknowledgment}
This research work is undertaken in the scope of the TRANSMIT ITN (www.transmit-ionosphere.net), funded by the Research Executive Agency within the 7TH  Framework Program of the European Commission, People Program, Initial Training Network, Marie Curie Actions - GA no 264476.
\sppart{references}
% BIBLIOGRAPHY
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{D:/Dropbox/library}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to delete the bold reference word or change it to the firs non bold word. As I read here before the command to set reference title empty is: `\renewcommand{\refname}{}`. But when I try to use this command, the latex does not change anything.

If you would need any additional information, please note me. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's important to know what class you're using.

Comment: yes, of course, forgot to include that `\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `natbib`, the best thing you can do is to say

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\sppart{references}}
```

in the preamble, so that

```
\sppart{acknowledgment}
This research ...

% BIBLIOGRAPHY
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{D:/Dropbox/library}

\end{document}
```

will suffice